# Docker container should only be accessible internally via a vSwitch on another server

Tags: docker, networking, ip, docker-network

I have 2 dedicated servers from the same provider:

- Debian 11 server with docker running many website/service that are reachable over the internet using a reverse proxy and the normal docker bdrige
- A Windows Server 2022

Both are connected via a ([vSwitch](https://docs.hetzner.com/robot/dedicated-server/network/vswitch.

I want to run a MongoDB Container on the debian server that should only be reachable internal by 192.168.100.1 on the windows server.

Using the normal docker bridge the MongoDB is reachable by the normal public IP of the server and by the internal ip

I tried creating a ipvlan network and configured the the internal ethernet adapter as parent, but didn't worked.

I look for any reference that could help me making that possible.

Thanks.

Comment: If I get it right you want to have two web servers and MongoDB(only vswitch reachable),you should place MongoDB on its own network.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking to complex. Another user helped me. I just bind the container on the internal ip: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish